# Error: Validation failed for one or more entities (C# MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm trying to get my JqGrid to update my database. I keep getting an Error: "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."

how do I find out what my actual error is or whats causing the error?

```
 // TODO:insert a new row to the grid logic here  
    [HttpPost]
    public string Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] AspNetUser obj)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Create");
        string msg;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.AspNetUsers.Add(obj);
                //db.AspNetUsers.Add(new AspNetUser { UserName = obj.UserName, Email = obj.Email });
                db.SaveChanges();
                msg = "Saved Successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Validation data not successfull";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

Comment: Its already telling you what to do - _See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."_

Comment: Also if *EntityValiationErrors* is non in the exception `ex`, try looking for it within the inner exception.

Comment: @stephenMuecke where do I find this property?

Comment: @codingYoshi excuse my ignorance but how do I do that?

Comment: Go to YouTube and type [debugging unhandled exception with Visual Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY4kLX_EPJY)

Comment: @Igorski88: It's enough to set breakpoint on the line `msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;` and to examine `ex` in Visual Studio (local variable window or watch window). You will find `InnerException` property of `ex` and, for example, `ex.InnerException.Message`

Comment: @Oleg I did just that and got the error msg: Property: Id - Error: The Id field is required. This is confusing because I excluded it:    `public string Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] AspNetUser obj)`

Comment: Answers go in the answer section, not the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this exception means the database is failing validation. This can occur if you have a set field in the database with a set character count and you are trying to save to that field a string which exceeds the database count.

Update your database string types with a 'varchar(max)' for example.

Hope this helps

Comment: Turns out "id" was not returning anything.